# How to remove entities from context concurrently?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, parallel-processing, dbcontext

Assume we have a List of entities to be removed:

```
var items = this.itemRepository.GetRange(1, 1000).ToList();
```

Instead of simple loop to delete `items`, I want to remove them concurrently like this:

```
items.AsParallel().ForAll(item =>
        {
            this.itemRepository.Remove(item);
        });
this.UnitOfWork.Commit();
```

How do you suggest me to perform delete like this?

Comment: The EF context is not thread safe, so I wouldn't do this. Also, I can't immediately see any worthwhile performance benefit with this: parallel `!=` faster.

Comment: Can't up-vote @AdamHouldsworth's comment enough.

Comment: Well, Why not you put it in answers? This seem's to be the right one.

Comment: @RezaOwliaei On request I can do, but on the face of it I didn't see much value in that immediately in case you were actually trying to address a further problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EF context is not thread safe, so I wouldn't do this.

If you need performance then parallel `!=` faster. Parallel code allows you to do more at the same time, but you tend to find that a single unit of work takes at least the same amount of time, but sometimes longer due to context switching etc, it's just that instead of doing 5 things one at a time, you are doing 5 things 5 at a time. This gets you more effective use of available hardware, and is less about performance and more about scalability and responsiveness.

---

As of EF 6 it exposes an asynchronous API for `async/await` support, but this again only allows one "concurrent" action against it. If you want to do multiple asynchronous reads, you will need one context per read action - this then simply puts the onus on the database to manage integrity.

Answer (score 1):

EF6 added a `RemoveRange` method to the `DbSet`

This is more efficient than removing a single object at a time because by default Entity Framework calls `DetectChanges` in the `Remove` method whereas `RemoveRange` calls it just once.

However, when you call `SaveChanges` EF still executes individual delete statements. There is a [proposal to Batch CUD](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/53) in a future version.

References:

[Entity Framework 6: The Ninja Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532202.aspx)

[RemoveRange - implemented in EF6. (with a bug fixed in 6.1)](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1050)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to EF6 if you are not already using it, then you can do the following:

```
this.itemRepository.RemoveRange(items);
```